# Is it possible to know the folder content? OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

I wanna try OneDrive Api for Android and I was taking a look at the methods and possibilities this Api offers on [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846808.aspx) and [this other one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn631814.aspx) but I don't see any way of listing the files a folder contains.

My App would need to upload some files to OneDrive, always using the same folder as root, say /MyFolder. The problem is that it only knows this root folder and all its content must be found out by means of recursive calls, that is, I list the files contained in /MyFolder and check if it's a folder or a file and in the first case list the files again it contains and so on.

Am I missing something or this Api doesn't provide such thing?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question? https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn631812.aspx

Comment: I'd already read that, but I don't know for sure if you can get that information from it. It seems you can get some information about the file/folder but not its content

Answer (score 0):

The Json object returned for a query against a Folder should contain a "data" property that is an array of children for the folder. You can see this in the interactive SDK (http://isdk.dev.live.com/dev/isdk/default.aspx) by playing with the "Reading Folder Properties" API.